# How to get confusion matrix when using model.fit_generator

Tags: keras, confusion-matrix

I am using model.fit_generator to train and get results for my binary (two class) model because I am giving input images directly from my folder. How to get confusion matrix in this case (TP, TN, FP, FN) as well because generally I use `confusion_matrix` command of `sklearn.metrics` to get it, which requires `predicted`, and `actual` labels. But here I don't have both. May be I can calculate predicted labels from `predict=model.predict_generator(validation_generator)` command. But I don't know how my model is taking input labels from my images. General structure of my input folder is:

```
train/
 class1/
     img1.jpg
     img2.jpg
     ........
 class2/
     IMG1.jpg
     IMG2.jpg
test/
 class1/
     img1.jpg
     img2.jpg
     ........
 class2/
     IMG1.jpg
     IMG2.jpg
     ........
```

and some blocks of my code is:

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('train',  
        target_size=(50, 50),  batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='binary',color_mode='grayscale')  


validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('test',
        target_size=(50, 50),batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='binary',color_mode='grayscale')

model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,steps_per_epoch=250 ,epochs=40,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=21 )
```

So the above code automatically takes two class inputs, but I don't know for which it consider class 0 and for which class 1.

Answer (score 5):

I've managed it in the following way, using `keras.utils.Sequence`.

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from keras.utils import Sequence


class MySequence(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # initialize
        # see manual on implementing methods

    def __len__(self):
        return self.length

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        # return index-th complete batch


# create data generator
data_gen = MySequence(evaluation_set, batch_size=10) 

n_batches = len(data_gen)

confusion_matrix(
    np.concatenate([np.argmax(data_gen[i][1], axis=1) for i in range(n_batches)]),    
    np.argmax(m.predict_generator(data_gen, steps=n_batches), axis=1) 
)
```

The implemented class returns batches of data in tuples, that allows not to hold all of them in RAM. Please, note that it must be implemented in `__getitem__`, and this method must return same batch for the same argument.

Unfortunately this code iterates data twice: first time, it creates array of true answers from returned batches, the second time it calls `predict` method of the model.

Answer (score 4):

```
probabilities = model.predict_generator(generator=test_generator)
```

will give us set of probabilities.

```
y_true = test_generator.classes
```

will give us true labels.

Because this is a binary classification problem, you have to find predicted labels. To do that you can use

```
y_pred = probabilities > 0.5
```

Then we have true labels and predicted labels on the test dataset. So, the confusion matrix is given by

```
font = {
'family': 'Times New Roman',
'size': 12
}
matplotlib.rc('font', **font)
mat = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
plot_confusion_matrix(conf_mat=mat, figsize=(8, 8), show_normed=False)
```

Comment: How did you identify this as a binary classification, sorry I am new to all  this

Comment: I noticed that in the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can view the mapping from class names to class indices by calling the attribute `class_indices` on your `train_generator` or `validation_generator` objects, as in

`train_generator.class_indices`

Comment: your help is valuable. when i type `train_generator.class_indices` and `validation_generator.class_indices` it gives me output `{'class1': 0, 'class2': 1}` . Suppose for test data i have 10 samples for both classes (total 20) so my input class  will be like [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]? and output classes i will get from `predict=model.predict_generator(validation_generator)` and after that i can get confusion matrix.

Comment: @Hitesh I'm a bit confused about your question. If you're asking about how does the output of class_indices actually map to your underlying labels, check out my video explaining this here. The output is shown around 4:20. https://youtu.be/pZoy_j3YsQg
Also, the output you get from predict_generator will be what you use for your confusion matrix.

Comment: can you expand a but on how to go from predict_generator to confusion matrix.

Comment: @bw4sz once you have the predictions from predict_generator, as well as the labels for those predictions, you can plot the results using sklearn's confusion matrix. I demonstrate the process here: https://youtu.be/km7pxKy4UHU Note, in that video, we're using predict() rather than predict_generator() for the predictions, but the concept is the same. After watching that one, if you want to see the process with predict_generator(), check out https://youtu.be/bfQBPNDy5EM around the 5:30 mark. The second video doesn't go through the full detailed process of creating the matrix like the first one.