# Keras: confusion matrix with predict_generator

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm not using "ImageDataGenerator" because I'm using hdf5 files. I used DataGenerator class (1) to feed data to the "model.fit_generator". So how can I get the confusion matrix given that I have batches of random data? Notice that I know how get it with "model.predict" using sklearn.

(1)
https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly#

Comment: Does anyone has an ideas?

Comment: Have you tried the answer suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47439789/10111931)?

Comment: Yes, but "validation_generator.classes" tells me that the method "classes" does not exist.

Comment: sorry I passed the wrong bookmark to you! I missed the fact that you are using a Sequence here. I had saved [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49943624/10111931) from an earlier SO thread. Maybe this is more useful in your case?